# Output multiple files SGE

Tags: bash, sungridengine

I have a `.sh` script that looks like this:

```
#$ -t 1-8
#$ -tc 8


#list of tasks
task_list=$( sed "${SGE_TASK_ID}q;d"  list_of_jobs.txt )

#python script 
./ldsc.py \
--h2 ${task_list} \
--ref-ld-chr /baselineLD. \
--out $cts_name \
```

I am running 8 jobs in parallel, but need each of them to output a separate file using the `--out` flag.

How can I do this?

The `list_of_jobs.txt` is a list of eight files (tasks) that get analyzed.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
…
file8.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.
`basename="${cts_name##*/}"`

and then
`--h2 $basename`  was the trick!